# Handle exceptions in a function that converts a camelCase string to a Formated String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

So, I've made a function that converts a `camelCasedString` to a `Properly Formatted String` using some answer here on Stack Overflow.

This is the function:

```
function camelCaseToString(str){
    var a = str.replace( /([A-Z])/g, " $1" );
    var b = a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1);
    return b;
}
```

problem is some outputs are not as I expect them to be, for example, these are wright:

```
camelCaseToString('exampleText'); // Example Text
camelCaseToString('ExampleText'); // Example Text
camelCaseToString('string(parenthesis)'); //String (parenthesis)
```

but I expect these:

```
camelCaseToString('string (Parenthesis)'); //gives String ( Parenthesis)
camelCaseToString('exampleWithRomanNumbersIII'); //gives Example With Roman Numbers I I I
```

to be `String (Parenthesis)` and `Example With Roman Numbers III` respectively.

Is there a way to to this with Regex? For the parenthesis case, I can simply use `replace('( ', '(')`, but how about the I I I. I need to detect if the Uppercase letters are 1 char long.

I think that this should be really easy to do with Regex but I don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific test cases this seems to work:

```
function camelCaseToString(str){
    var a = str.replace( /([^A-Z( ]+)([A-Z(])/g, "$1 $2" );
    var b = a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
str.replace( /(\(?[A-Z][A-Za-z])/g, " $1" );
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach will be to match cases when there is a lowercase letter followed with an uppercase one (`([a-z])([A-Z])`) or (`|`) when there is start of string position or a non-word char before a lowercase char (`\b([a-z])`):

```js
function camelCaseToString(str){
    var rx = /([a-z])([A-Z])|\b([a-z])/g;
    var a = str.replace(rx, function($0, $1, $2, $3, $4) {
      return $1 ? $1 + " " + $2 : $3.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $3.slice(1);
    } );
    return a;
}

console.log(camelCaseToString('exampleText'));
console.log(camelCaseToString('ExampleText')); 
console.log(camelCaseToString('string(parenthesis)')); 
console.log(camelCaseToString('string (Parenthesis)'));
console.log(camelCaseToString('exampleWithRomanNumbersIII'));
```

The match is passed to the replace callback method, and if Group 1 matched, the space is inserted between the lowercase letter (`$1`) and the uppercase one (`$2`) (see `$1 ? $1 + " " + $2`) and when Group 1 did not match (meaning Group 3 matched, a lowercase ASCII letter after a word boundary), the first letter is turned uppercase (see `: $3.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $3.slice(1)`).